# Bash repeating my directory and can not call the file

Tags: linux, bash, recursion

have to use a .sh script to unpack and prep some databases. The code is the following:

```
#
# Downloads and unzips all required data for AlphaFold.
#
# Usage: bash download_all_data.sh /path/to/download/directory
set -e

DOWNLOAD_DIR="$1"

for f in $(ls ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/*.tar.gz)
do
  tar --extract --verbose --file="${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/${f}" /
      --directory="${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/mmseqs_dbs"
  rm "${f}"
  BASENAME="$(basename {f%%.*})"
  DB_NAME="${BASENAME}_db"
  OLD_PWD=$(pwd)
  cd "${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/mmseqs_dbs" 
  mmseqs tar2exprofiledb "${BASENAME}" "${DB_NAME}"
  mmseqs createindex "${DB_NAME}" "${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/tmp/"
  cd "${OLD_PWD}"
done
```

When I run the code, I got that error:

```
(openfold_venv) watson@watson:~/pedro/openfold$ sudo bash scripts/prep_mmseqs_dbs.sh data/
tar: data//data//colabfold_envdb_202108.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I don`t understand why the code repeats my "DOWNLOAD_DIR", the correct should be :

```
data/colabfold_envdb_202108.tar.gz
```

and not

```
data//data//colabfold_envdb_202108.tar.gz
```

Could anyone help me?

New code:

```
set -e

DOWNLOAD_DIR="$1"

for f in ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/*.tar.gz; 
do
  tar --extract --verbose --file="$f" /
      --directory="${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/mmseqs_dbs"
  rm "${f}"
  BASENAME="$(basename {f%%.*})"
  DB_NAME="${BASENAME}_db"
  OLD_PWD=$(pwd)
  cd "${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/mmseqs_dbs" 
  mmseqs tar2exprofiledb "${BASENAME}" "${DB_NAME}"
  mmseqs createindex "${DB_NAME}" "${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/tmp/"
  cd "${OLD_PWD}"
done
```

Comment: With `$1` = `data/`, your `ls ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/*.tar.gz` returns `data//colabfold_envdb_202108.tar.gz`. So parameter `f` takes this exact value. Then `${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/${f}` expands as `data//data//colabfold_envdb_202108.tar.gz`. Try `tar ... --file="$f" ...` Note that parsing the `ls` output is bad practice. `ls` is for humans. Better use `for f in ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/*.tar.gz; do `.

Comment: Thanks for answer...it works but Igot new error: `tar: /: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`  the new code was edited above

Comment: To continue your `tar` command on another line, use `\ `, not `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question: why is it repeating? Because you are repeating it in your code:

```
for f in ${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/*.tar.gz; 
do
  tar --extract --verbose --file="${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/$f"
```

If `f` is `downloads/file.tar.gz` then `${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/${f}` will resolve to `downloads/downloads/file.tar.tgz`.

As to your second question: the escape character is the backslash `\`, not the forward slash. Your multiline command should look like this:

```
tar --extract --verbose --file="${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/${f}" \
    --directory="${DOWNLOAD_DIR}/mmseqs_dbs"
```